# How do I search Kibana field.keyword?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-7

I'm on Kibana v7.4.2

I have 2 fields setup: `message` and `message.keyword`

If I just go to the Discover tab and search `message.keyword:*` it shows everything `message:*` does.

I want to search for a specific substring such as "[Special Message]". As I understand it, I have to use the `message.keyword` because `message:"[Special Message]"` will always be fuzzy. It will return entries that have `this is a special message` and not exactly `here is [Special Message]` which is insufficient for me.

However `message.keyword:"[Special Message]"` always returns *No results match your search criteria*
This behavior is observed the same in both KQL and Lucene.

How do I search field.keyword for something?

Comment: Is "Special Message" a sub-string of the whole message field?

Comment: yes, it is indeed a substring. And it isn't a field that we can filter for.